# Casting interface to child interface

Tags: java, interface

How can I cast a interface to the child interface?

Example:

```java
public interface A { ..... }
public interface B extends A { ..... }
... 
A objA = generateA();
B objB = (B) objA; 
...
```

Comment: just as you have done is correct.

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? What is your problem with it?

Comment: I made another type of error. Thanks so much anyway.

Comment: you will most likely get runtime exception by casting from superclass to subclass unless the class for objA also implements interface B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done in your example is correct.

```
ParentInterface objA = new ChildImplementation();
ChildInterface objB = (ChildInterface) objA;
```

You will get a runtime cast exception if objA is not really of the ChildInterface type.

Comment: I made another type of error. Thanks so much anyway.